# Configure Implementation Class of Abstract Factory with Spring

Tags: java, spring

For my application, I have a `Scale` interface and multiple classes implementing this interface, for example `NormalizedScale`, `LogScale`, etc. In one of my Services, I need to create many Scales, and I want to use Spring to define which implementation of the Scale it should create. How would I implement something like this?

--

I was thinking to create a factory `ScaleFactory`, like in the Abstract Factory Pattern, which I could call `ScaleFactory.getScale()` to get a Scale of whichever implementation I configured in the Spring XML:

```
class ScaleFactory {
    Class<? extends Scale> scaleImplClass;
    public static Scale getScale() {
        return scaleImplClass.newInstance();
    }
}


Scale myScale = ScaleFactory.getScale();
```

But with that approach, how could I configure which implementation the ScaleFactory should use from Spring XML?

--

An alternative would be to make the `ScaleFactory` a `@Service`, and then autowire the ScaleFactory into my service:

```
@Autowired
ScaleFactory scaleFactory;

...

Scale myScale = scaleFactory.getScale();
```

Then I can use an autowired property in the ScaleFactory to define the `scaleImplClass`. But that seems weird because my Factory is also a Service and I have an instance of that factory.

--

Another approach would be to have the `Class scaleImplementationClass` property in my *service* instead of the ScaleFacotry and use the ScaleFactory like so:

```
@Value("${scaleImplementationClass}")
Class scaleImplementationClass

...

Scale myScale = ScaleFactory.getScale(scaleImplementationClass);
```

But then the factory is quite pointless because I could also just as well run `scaleImplementationClass.newInstance()`.

Comment: What are you looking to get with this approach? The abstract factory is actually replacing a bit of what Spring wants to do for you, and pushes a little away from dependency injection, which is where you're feeling the resistance. What you could do, instead, to make this work naturally is simply `@Autowire private Scale scale` into any of your classes that need an instance of `Scale`. Spring will automatically find whatever implementation you have defined in your XML and load that in its place. You won't need the factory class.

Comment: Colin, if I `@Autowire Scale scale`, I will only get _one_ scale, but I need to create *many* Scales. This is why I think I need a Factory. Another alternative I guess would be to create multiple factories (one for each implementation of Scale) and then @Autowire the correct factory.

Comment: That makes sense. See my answer below and let me know if it helps you. (Edit: Removed my answer, realized it wasn't directly answering your question. Clearing it up).

Comment: Added my updated answer back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of different Spring-like ways you can handle this. The approach I have personally gone for looks a bit like this:

```
public interface ScaleFactory {

    public Scale newInstance();
    public String type();

}

public class FirstScaleFactory implements ScaleFactory {

    public Scale newInstance() {
        return new FirstScale();
    }

    public String type() {
        return "first";
    }    

}

public class SecondScaleFactory implements ScaleFactory {

    public Scale newInstance() {
        return new SecondScale();
    }

    public String type() {
        return "second";
    }    

}

public class ScaleManager {

    private final Map<String, ScaleFactory> factories;

    @Autowired
    public ScaleManager(List<ScaleFactory> factories) {
        this.factories = factories.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> f.type(), Function::identity));
    }

    public Scale newInstance(String type) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(factories.get(type))
            .map(factory -> factory.newInstance())
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }

}
```

With this approach, your `ScaleManager` is a standard Spring bean that can be wired into any class that needs a scale instance. At initialization time, it gets all `ScaleFactories` that are defined in the Spring context, and autowires them in as a `List<ScaleFactory>`, which is then converted to a `Map` (where the `ScaleFactory` type is the key). This avoids you needing to worry about class names of `Scale`, and gives your the ability to change them later (as long as you keep the `type` key consistent)`

Your `ScaleFactory` implementations can then do whatever they need to do. For example, if you have one type of `Scale` that you know is immutable, you can have the factory return the same instance every time. Alternatively you can have every invocation return a separate instance - the instantiation of the `Scale` is up to the implementation-dependent factory.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use "Qualifiers" which is basically going to point to a specific "named" bean. By default the bean names are the name of your classes, with the first letter in lower case (MyClass -> myClass). If you want to define your own names you can do as follow :

```
@Service("customizedBeanName")
```

You would end up doing something like this :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("logScale")
private Scale logScale;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("anotherScale")
private Scale anotherScale;
```

Comment: But this gives me only those two scales, and I can't create new scales from that.

Comment: So you need a list of scale in your class ? How are you going to use it ? Would conditional instantiation help you : http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/ ?

Answer (score 0):

As for spring 5.x there's a simpler and cleaner way of doing this. I have decided to use [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) annotation but you may choose any @Conditional* of your preference.

Here's the thing, I've have simplified to extreme:

```java
public interface MyService {}

@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myService", name = "Impl", havingValue = "Some")
public class SomeService implements MyService {}

@Service
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "myService", name = "Impl", havingValue = "Foo")
public class FooService implements MyService {}

@Service
public class SimpleService {

  @Autowired
  SimpleService(MyService service) {
    // service instance will depend on configuration
  }
}
```

I'm using springboot so I've decided to use `application.properties` in order to set values via environment variables like this:

```
myService.Impl=${MY_SERVICE_IMPL}
```

Then, I have a fully dynamic injection based on environment variables that may be passed to a docker container for instance.