# How to implement abstract factory using spring framework

Tags: spring, factory, abstract

I am trying to implement abstract factory pattern in spring but getting bean reference exceptions. Should the abstract class be auto wired. Appreciate if any one can guide

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34465900/configure-implementation-class-of-abstract-factory-with-spring